# Downloading encrypted binary file using C# Windows Phone is missing data

Tags: c#, java, encryption, binary, windows-phone-7.1

I need to download an encrypted xml binary file from a url which has been encrypted using JAVA. I have managed to encrypt the file in JAVA, then add the file in my WP7 project and decrypt using c# and read the file into my app succesfully.

I need to now store the file on a web server so the app can access it and I'm finding that the file is not complete or in the incorrect format when I download it and the decryption does not work.

I have tried using both WebClient and HttpWebRequest and both give me the same result. The xml encoded file is approximately 17000 bytes but the file downloaded from both of these methods return a file about 16000 bytes long. I think the downloaded file is missing end of line characters but I can't verify this. The code I'm using at the moment to download the file is pretty simple and is as follows:

```
private void GetFile()
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
        String url = "http://url/encodedfile.txt";            
        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));

     }

    void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        string s = e.Result;

        byte[] encodedFile = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(e.result);

        //decrypt file....
```

Looking at the encrypted data they look very similar but the length of encodedFile is not the correct length of the original encrypted file.I've debugged this and copied the characters in encodedFile to TextPad its all on one line. I'm not sure if that's the issue or not but I've looked everywhere on how to download a binary file and most suggestions are to use HttpWebRequest but I get the exact same result so I don't think that is the issue.

Any help appreaciated.

Comment: check if the webserver is returning the correct "Content-Length" Header ?

Comment: "an encrypted xml binary file from a url which has been encrypted using JAVA." We'll need to see some java code if you're going to need help

Comment: Have yoou tried `client.DownloadDataAsync`? It seems you try to read encrypted binary data as string.

Comment: I didn't include the JAVA because I know the JAVA encrypting is working and the c# decrypting is working because I've generated the encrypted file using JAVA and then added it as an existing file in my WP project. Then I've read the encrypted file, decrypted it and put the string in to listbox items using c# so i know the problem isn't there. The problem is when I store the encrypted file on a webserver, then download it the file doesn't decrypt correctly. If you still think having the JAVA will help I'll post that up.

Comment: @I4V DownloadDataAsync doesn't exist in c# for WP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DownloadString` will try to read the data as an unicode string. Since you're downloading binary data, it's no wonder the output isn't correct. Try using `WebClient.OpenReadAsync` instead:

```
private void GetFile()
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();

    webClient.OpenReadCompleted += OpenReadCompleted;

    string url = "http://url/encodedfile.txt";         

    webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(url));
}

private void OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Decrypt the contents of e.Result
}
```